# Update SQL Query not executing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system in which when a user uses a coupon, a "taken" column is filled with a string which I run `IS NULL` against to render the coupon consumed. My problem is that my `update_coupon` function is not updating the column as I expect. The first time it worked, but then I must have changed something and subsequent queries no longer work.

Sorry for the noob question. Thank you for any help.

```php
    function is_valid_coupon($card_code){
        global $db;
        $code = sha1($card_code);
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM giftcards where card_code = :code';
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':code', $code);
        $statement->execute();
        $valid = ($statement->rowCount() == 1);
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $valid;
    }

    function update_coupon($card_code){
        global $db;
        $code = sha1($card_code);
        $query = "
        UPDATE `giftcards`
        SET taken = used
        WHERE card_code = :card_code";
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->bindValue(':card_code', $code);
        $statement->execute();
        $statement->closeCursor();
    }
```

Which are executed like so:

```php
    if ($card_code){ 
        if (is_valid_coupon($card_code)){
          update_coupon($card_code);
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"I must have changed something"* - what exactly?

Comment: In `SET taken = used` do you mean to set it to a value of used - which should be `SET taken = 'used'` with quotes?

Comment: You call `is_valid_coupon()` but at no point do you also check if the coupon has already been used, so in theory you can keep on using the same coupon - if that matters at all.

Comment: Wouldn't is_valid_coupon return a boolean if used or not? I then use that value to update_coupon.

Comment: I just found out is_valid_coupon returns false, I don't understand why because the coupon should be in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is causing the problem:

```
SET taken = used
```

you need to put apostrophes before and after used:

```
SET taken = 'used'
```

Comment: I did try this and it still did not update the database.

Comment: @user123 What is card_code that is passed to the query?

Comment: $card_code = 
            strtoupper(
                       substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 5) 
            
                       . '-' . 
                       
                       substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 5) 
                       
                       . '-' . 
            
                       substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 5)
        ); **so it's the coupon code

Comment: @user123 mt_rand() is random. If you randomize this value, then you will get a random value as a result. Now, since you are filtering by this random value (calculated by Mersenne Twister algorithm), it's quite possible that it will not match any of the records you store, hence not updating anything. Can you take a value that you actually have and hard-code it into your SQL temporally just to see whether the filter is the only problem?